# How make default profile picture in express js

Tags: php, express

How can I can make default profile picture when the user have not upload there picture? I want to display default profile picture for them, like png.
I have done some thing similar in php but I don't know how to change it to nodejs express code.
This is what have done in php:

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$defaultProfilePicture = "static/" . basename("0000.png");
$defaultContentType = "image/png;";
```

How can I change it to express code? Please help me by saving my days.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using mongoose in your user model make a field for profile picture and you can set a default value

Example

```
const schema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  role: { type: String, default: 'guitarist' }
});
```

Comment: Yes am using mongoose but I have model for profile picture

Comment: What you should do is add the profile picture field for the user model and have a default value for it set and then when a user wants to add a profile picture they can go to their account and upload a photo then you can update it in the database